# Ошибка в консоли XMLHttpRequest

Tags: mysql

В консоли выходит такая ошибка:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'javascript:;' from origin
'https://teamtimeofficial.info' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross
origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data,
chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

На сайте не работает регистрация, в базу данных новые данные не грузятся, с чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 0):

В ошибке явно сказано, что доступ заблокированн CORS.
Подробнее про CORS вы можете почитать тут [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

---

Если вас интересует более точный ответ, то пожалуйста конкретизируйте вопрос.